# Use Cut to trim a string of file permissions

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, cut

I'm trying to remove the group and all users part from a permissions string. Such as `-rwxr-xr-x` and I want it to be `-rwx` and then take off the leading dash to make it `rwx`

Right now I'm getting the permissions string via this code: `filePerms=$(stat --format=%A $path)` where `$path` is just a any directory to a file.

Here my attempt at using cut to get rid of the 4th character and on `filePermsTest=$(cut -c1- $filePerms)` but I get this error:

```
cut: invalid option -- 'r'
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
59M   2014-03-21 19:25   -rw-r--r--   ./old/VMwareTools-9.6.2-1688356.tar.gz
```

Here's the part of the `cut` command I'm trying that use: `N-     from N'th byte, character or field, to end of line`

For reference here's the normal output of my code **(This doesn't have much to do with the question. It's just to give you a reference of what's going on and how this will be used)**:

```
Size   Date      Time     Permissions   File
--------------------------------------------------------
59M   2014-03-21 19:25   -rw-r--r--   ./old/VMwareTools-9.6.2-1688356.tar.gz
9.2M   2014-03-21 19:24   -rw-r--r--   ./old/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/icu/icudt44l.dat
7.6M   2013-07-07 21:21   -rwxr-xr-x   ./old/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text
4.8M   2014-08-26 23:51   -rwxrwxr-x   ./old/sublime_text_3/sublime_text
```

I think somehow part of permission string is being taken in as an argument.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: To get characters 2-4 from the permission string. For example `-rw-r--r--` to `rw-`

Comment: Why don't you use `ls -l` instead of `stat`? Permissions is the first column in the output of `ls -l`

Comment: The problem isn't the column. The permissions are in a string all of their own from stat. I'm just trying to cut that string which in my code is called `$filePerms`

Comment: `cut` is designed to take a filename as an argument.  You have a shell variable, not a filename.  The obvious thing to do is to make it a file by echoing it and passing it to the stdin of `cut`.  e.g. `echo $fileperms | cut -c 2-4`.

Comment: @Angel: Yes, because the permission string of a file begins with `-` it is being interpreted as an argument, hence the error message. But as Tony explained, it still wouldn't do what you want even if the string you passed didn't begin with `-`, since `cut` expects the data its processing to come from a file, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `stat --format=%A filename | cut -c 2-4`.

This picks out the second to fourth characters, which are the ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk's `substr` function to cut out some characters from a particular column.

```
command | awk 'NR>2{$4=substr($4,2,3)}1'
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
Size   Date      Time     Permissions   File
--------------------------------------------------------
59M   2014-03-21 19:25   -rw-r--r--   ./old/VMwareTools-9.6.2-1688356.tar.gz
9.2M   2014-03-21 19:24   -rw-r--r--   ./old/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/icu/icudt44l.dat
7.6M   2013-07-07 21:21   -rwxr-xr-x   ./old/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text
4.8M   2014-08-26 23:51   -rwxrwxr-x   ./old/sublime_text_3/sublime_text
$ awk 'NR>2{$4=substr($4,2,3)}1' file
Size   Date      Time     Permissions   File
--------------------------------------------------------
59M 2014-03-21 19:25 rw- ./old/VMwareTools-9.6.2-1688356.tar.gz
9.2M 2014-03-21 19:24 rw- ./old/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/icu/icudt44l.dat
7.6M 2013-07-07 21:21 rwx ./old/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text
4.8M 2014-08-26 23:51 rwx ./old/sublime_text_3/sublime_text
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here? I'm not too familiar with awk or what command does in this code.

Comment: Also how do I awk on a string?